# Dynamically modify forms in Symfony2 without Javascript?

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I was reading the [How to dynamically Generate Forms Based on user Data](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#how-to-dynamically-generate-forms-based-on-user-data) 
from the Symfony2 cook book.

I'm seeking functionality similar to the link above.

However, if I understand correctly it suggests to use AJAX to update the form.

Is this correct?

This example is desired functionality I'm seeking:

Step 1:

```
Form //Controller locationAction
 ________________
|
|
| Country Select 
|
| |Please select...|
|
|      ____
|     |Next|
 _______________
```

Expectations after Hitting Next

- Submits to the same locationAction method
- form appears with previously selected result.
- Skips validation until all dynamic fields are present.
- New State choice field appears, choices depend on user submitted Country field.

Step 2:

```
|
v

Form //Controller locationAction
 ________________
|
|
| Country Select 
|
|      |U.S.|
|
|  
|      State
|  |Please select ....| //List is displayed that corresponds to their selected country
|
|      ______
|     |Submit|
 _______________
```

After pushing submit

- Validates both Country and State then performs an action that depends on the form (dynamic fields included) being validated first.

Is it possible to obtain the above result using `Form Subscribers/Form Listeners` alone in one form with no JavaScript?

Or do I need to use JavaScript/create a separate form?

Comment: As far as I know, you can't modify dynamically the content of a page without JavaScript.

Comment: @A.L The page does reload after a `GET/POST` request when you push "next". The dynamic field can appear then.

Comment: Strictly speaking, that's not *dynamically* if you reload the page.

Comment: @A.L We're speaking about different contexts. I'm clarifying that I meant it for the internal framework and not the request type.

Comment: Ok, I see, sorry for the misunderstanding .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, if I understand correctly it suggests to use AJAX to update
>   the form.

No it doesn't. You can just submit the form to the same action. After each step, it's a new request/response and the dynamic form generation is handled at server side, not by javascript.

And perhaps, [dynamic-generation-for-submitted-forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#dynamic-generation-for-submitted-forms) is exactly your use case (it's another section on the same guide).

Comment: Awesome, it does work. Just need to make sure validation is turned on for the dynamic option.